# Getting the number of the caller in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-node

I want to know the current callers(client) Phone Number and then be able to verify it from my HubSpot CRM to see which language my client speaks. Then Enqueue the call to the agent that speaks the language or give the Caller an option to choose the preferred language.

Anyhoo

**Right now my goal is to just get the number of the caller(client).**

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log(event);
     //const request = require('request');
     //const client = require('twilio');
     const res = new Twilio.Response();
     res.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     res.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS POST');
     res.appendHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     res.appendHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    var phoneNumber = event.From; //|| [ "+63XXXXXXXXXX" ];
    const apiUrl = "https://myapiurl.com/contact-details.php?number="+phoneNumber;
    fetch(apiUrl,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then( response =>{
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(json=>{
        console.log(json);
        res.setBody(json);
        callback(null,res);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
        callback();
    });
};
```

Also let me know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your code shows you getting `event.From`. This is the number of the person calling, so you have already done it!